# Found null SObject at position 0 in data taken from Batchable Map

Tags: apex, batch, error

I am running the below code but getting a DML error for my database.delete statement

> found null SObject at position 0 error.

```
global class RevenueSchedulerBatch implements Database.Batchable < sObject > {
    global static List < Revenue_Schedule__c > toInsert = new List < Revenue_Schedule__c > ();
    global static List < Revenue_Schedule__c > toDelete = new List < Revenue_Schedule__c > ();
    global static Map < Id, Revenue_Schedule__c > lineIdToRevShed = new Map < Id, Revenue_Schedule__c > ();

    /*   global static void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
          RevenueScheduler1 batchable = new RevenueScheduler1();
          Database.executeBatch(batchable,1);
      }
    */
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        for (Revenue_Schedule__c r: [SELECT Id, Line_Item__c FROM Revenue_Schedule__c WHERE Line_Item__r.timeStamp__c = : system.today()]) {
            lineIdToRevShed.put(r.Line_Item__c, r);

        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Amount_LC_Total__c, Opportunity_Local_to_USD_Rate__c, Net_Cost_LC__c, Bonus_Line_Item__c, Days_to_Run__c
            FROM Line_Item__c
            WHERE timeStamp__c = : system.today()
        ]);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < Line_Item__c > lis) {

        for (Line_Item__c li: lis) {
            //If it is a bonus line, skip the line.

            toDelete.add(lineIdToRevShed.get(li.Id));
            if (toDelete.size() > 0) {
                system.debug('Hello' + toDelete.size());
                Database.Delete(toDelete);
                Database.EmptyRecycleBin(toDelete);
            }
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if they are related to your issue but I have 2 questions: Why should toDelete need to be global and not just used in the execute scope ? And why are you doing the delete statement in the for-loop ?  I'd try to refactor those first and than see if the error is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have data that you want to be preserved across calls to `execute` you need to add the marker interface `Database.Stateful`. In your current code the content of the `lineIdToRevShed` is not being preserved, so when a lookup in that map is done null is returned.

See the "Using State in Batch Apex" section of the [Using Batch Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) documentation.

It looks like `Revenue_Schedule__c` is a child of `Line_Item__c` but if there is more than one `Revenue_Schedule__c` per `Line_Item__c` your map will only contain the last one so some will be missed.

If I understand your data model correctly, this approach (making use of a [relationship query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)) will solve your problem (but double check the `Revenue_Schedules__r` relationship name):

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
             SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Amount_LC_Total__c,
                     Opportunity_Local_to_USD_Rate__c, Net_Cost_LC__c,
                     Bonus_Line_Item__c, Days_to_Run__c,
                     (select Id from Revenue_Schedules__r)
             FROM Line_Item__c
             WHERE timeStamp__c = : system.today()
    ]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < Line_Item__c > lis) {
    Set<Id> toDelete = new Set<Id>();
    for (Line_Item__c li: lis) {
        //If it is a bonus line, skip the line.
        for (Revenue_Schedule__c rs : li.Revenue_Schedules__r) {
            toDelete.add(rs.Id);
        }
    }
    Database.Delete(toDelete);
    Database.EmptyRecycleBin(toDelete);
}
```

The immediately above approach does not require the `Database.Stateful` marker.